# Poly map with simple hovers

Tags: css, html, dictionary, interactive

Can anybody tell my how map on http://ubytujnaslovensku.sk/sk/ was created/how to create something simillar? 
there's only one image....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map on the website you have provided is using two images. The first image is the actual IDLE map, the second is a shadow version of it.

The shadow version is simply a 'Sprite', where all of the areas is inset and is looking however they want it to look, when you hover it.

Whenever you then hover a zone JavaScript sees it and sets the 'Background-position' variable according to the country you are hovering.

The Sprite image is [shown here](http://ubytujnaslovensku.sk/assets/img/mapa.png).

I would suggest you to get a deeper understanding of [sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) before trying to accomplish a similar map.